# Typescript: dealing with keyof generic types

Tags: typescript

I have a React + TS application and I have a problem. I'm writing a function to filter some data:

```
    function matchesFilter(element: T, filter: Filters) {
      const { name, options } = filter;
      return options.filter(selected => selected).some(value => value === element[name]);
    }
```

I'm using the generic type T because the elements to filter can be of different formats.
This is how I formalized `Filters`:

```
export type Filter = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  selected: boolean;
};

export type Filters = {
  name: string;
  options: Filter[];
};
```

The problem is that I have this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.   No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)

at `element[name]`.

I guess typescript is trying to say that a type "string" (`name`) cannot be used as key to access a property of the object `element`, but how can I solve this?

UPDATE: this is a more complete version of the custom hook I'm writing, the type  is a generic type:

```
const useUpdateFilters = <T>(elements: T[], filterConfiguration: Filters[]) => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(filterConfiguration);
  const [filteredObjects, setFilteredRequests] = useState<T[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function matchesFilter(element: T, filter: Filters) {
      const { name, options } = filter;
      return options.filter(selected => selected).some(value => value === element[name]);
    }

    function matchesAllFilters(element: T, filtersToMatch: Filters[]) {
      return filtersToMatch.every(filterToMatch => matchesFilter(element, filterToMatch));
    }

    setFilteredRequests(elements.filter((element: T) => matchesAllFilters(element, filters)));
  }, [filters, elements]);

  return {
    filters,
    filteredObjects,
  };
};

export default useUpdateFilters;
```

Comment: What's `T` here?  It's very helpful for code in questions to be a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/mpDnxm).  It seems like you want `element` to be of type `{[k: string]: Filter}` for this to work, but it's just `T`, whatever that is.

Comment: Now you have `useState()` in there.  Is this question specific to react?  If so, please tag it as such.  If not, please remove the dependency in your question.  The point of a [mcve] is that someone else can use it to demonstrate the issue for themselves.  Ideally you'd produce something that can be dropped as-is into any TypeScript IDE.  Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zPEN) (and see the possible solution in there).

Answer (score 0):

As you clearly expect all elements to have name, you can pass this expectation to TS and it should stop complaining:

```
const useUpdateFilters = <T extends {name:string}>(elements: T[]...
```